# unknown error: path is not absolute Appium -Selenium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate mobile app and i got some problem in file upload. I found my image file path as

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171030_115657.jpg
```

and I used it

```
driver.findElement(By.name("image")).sendKeys("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171030_115657.jpg);
```

and I get error:

```
unknown error: path is not absolute:
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171030_115657.jpg
```

please help

Comment: From where you are uploading yourimage?

Comment: from my Mobile device and i found my image path using adb

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt this selenium-like approach with `sendKeys(filePath)` will work for **native** Android app, I cannot find information about UiAutomator can handle it or any user success story on it.

What I did in the same case (and looks like many other people do) is open gallery where you actually adding a file and select needed image by clicking it. This is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about sendKeys works with android device or not. 
But in path there should be two slashes instead of 1 slash.

Path should be like

```
//storage//emulated//0//DCIM//Camera//IMG_20171030_115657.jpg
```

Do googling about escape sequences